# How do I interact with Google Docs from Android?

Tags: android, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm interested in adding functionality to my application to read from and write to a google docs spreadsheet.

I've seen other Android applications do this but I'm having trouble figuring out how I would implement this functionality in my own apps.

Any information you could give me to at least get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading about the Google docs api.

Read this : 
Java android client api for [android](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android)

then take a look at a [sample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/docs/DocumentResumableUploadDemo.java) that uploads a document to google docs.

Comment: @Renu i got authenticates now..how do i fetch data from google docs?

Comment: +1 Hi @Reno , I want to do something like in Android have some string values like products name and now want to store it parmenantlly..I decided to store to Google Docs ...is this feasible? have you any ideas?..any sample examples? Tutorial? Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: @Faste You mean you want to use Google docs as a [spreadsheet/database](http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/).

Comment: Kind of, just simple data storage and retrival, have used GData Api for that, All done now.! Thanks

Comment: I am using gdata api for google docs, after authentication I got list of files in google drive, but when I trying to download file (e.g. "docx", "pdf", "ppt") then api throws "com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found" exception. 

Please help me what I have to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can start with the [Google Docs api](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/). Looks like it lets you create,edit,view documents.

Comment: i got authenticates now..how do i fetch data from google docs?

Comment: Why does your link go to Google Drive API, instead of Google Docs API? I have found Google Sheets API, Google Slides API, but am not able to find Google Docs API. Where will that API be?